# On the equivalence principle

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, time-dilation, equivalence-principle

In its simplest version, it states that

> the effects of a uniform gravitational field are indistinguishable from those of a uniform linear acceleration of the frame of reference

The thing is, you can peacefully stand on the surface of the Earth for a year (or more), but you can’t accelerate uniformly at $9.8 m/s^2$ for a year, since by then you’d have already surpassed light speed.

You might say that, in specialty relativity, a body actually can uniformly accelerate forever without ever reaching the speed of light, because its proper time will adjust accordingly.

But that’s still a noticeable difference, isn’t it? If I’m sitting still on Earth surface, my clock will always tick exactly at the same pace, while in the accelerated reference frame, the clock has to slow down, eventually much more than that on Earth.

My point is, the two scenarios seem not that equivalent after all

Comment: From your point of view, your wristwatch will always tick at the same rate, wherever you are in the universe, whatever acceleration you undergo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These considerations about the principle of equivalence fall in the category of cases where there is a tension between local assessment and global assessment.

Example:
Locally any part of the Earth's surface is - as far as the naked eye can tell - flat, but globally the shape of the Earth is (to a very good approximation) a sphere.

What you are proposing is to compare the amount of proper time that elapses for you to the amount of proper time that elapses for a population of clocks all located at a significant *distance* to you.

Of course that brings out the difference that you are pointing out.

The thing is, the principle of equivalence does not assert 1-on-1 correspondence on *global* scale.

The thrust of the principle of equivalence is similar to the thrust of the argument that Galilei offered to argue for what we now call the Principle of Relativity of Inertial Motion.

Imagine you are in a cabin inside of a ship that is in motion over perfectly smooth water. Create some mechanical setup in the cabin, such as a swinging pendulum. Can the inside-the-cabin mechanical setup provide you with a way to assess the velocity of the ship? It cannot.

The thrust of the thought demonstration associated with the principle of equivalence is as follows: a local setup, of any kind (mechanical, electromagnetic, nuclear), will not detect a difference between uniform acceleration with respect to geometrically flat spacetime, or being stationary relative to a source of curvature of spacetime.

The question of how local is local enough is not particularly relevant; that is not the thrust of the principle of equivalence. The thrust of the principle of equivalence is that if it would not hold good then *a local experiment* would be available that would tell you the difference.